# Different styles of narrative. Should you stick to the norm when starting out?

Tags: dialogue

I noticed that many authors use different ways of conveying dialogue, from conventional to unquoted ramblings mixed with explanatory sentencing. Are these types of artistic license with punctuation like Cormac McCarthy better for someone with a foothold as an author or should you stick to strict structure from the beginning because it could lead to bad styling and grammar?

Comment: Any answer is **OPINION-BASED**. Poor grammar and style are distracting to the reader, not 'creative' choices – but if a looser punctuation style appeals to you, try it and see.

Comment: @wetcircuit Most questions on this channel yield opinion-based, rather than strictly factual, answers. Such is the nature of discussing a creative field.

Comment: @Divizna "because it could lead to bad styling and grammar?" <–– this is the opinion/assumption, which is what I wrote in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I say with dialog that you should take your grammar book and chuck it out the window, but you still need it for narration.   To that end, perfect grammar in dialog is not important because nobody speaks grammatically perfect English.  And the way someone says something can tell you a lot about who they are.  As a personal preference, I would try to avoid phonetic spelling for the effect of accents (I call it Hagriding, after the Harry Potter character Hagrid, who had a thick accent that was portrayed in the books with deliberate misspellings to portray it... but it always made his dialog difficult to read despite the fact that the audio books and the films make him one of the best characters to listen to.).  If you over sell it, it becomes difficult for the reader to understand what is being said.  (That in mine, on the rare occasion I write a character with a British Accent, I do take pains to write their dialog with British Spelling rather than American spelling I would use of other characters dialog and narration.   My Brit would say "Colour" while my American would say "Color" so I'm not wholly immune... but most of my characters get the accent drop in the dialog tag, rather than poor spelling.

I also will play with punctuation if characters are speaking in languages I do not know.  Typically I use quotes followed by the Less than (<) to open dialog that is translated for the reader's benefit but in universe non-speakers do not understand and close with "Greater Than" symbol (>) before the closing quote.

> "<Who are you?  What do you want?>" asked the Guard.
>
> "Sorry, I don't speak Spanish!" Alice said slowly, as she raised her hands.  She felt like she could kick herself for taking High School French.

Here, the dialog conveys the language gap without openly saying what the unusual punction means.  This method is one of my own, but it didn't originate from my own mind but from two sources:  Comic Books, which tend put the <> around dialog that is translated in speech bubbles (since they don't use quotes in speech bubbles) but also have better indicators of internal though and vocal dialog (In the case of the former, the bubble will be more cloud like and have disconnected smaller clouds leading to the character thinking, while speech bubbles are typically oval shaped and have a direct arrow leading to the speaker).  The other source was the use of "thought speech" in Animorphs, a sort of directed telepathic speech between characters without the ability to actually speak (as is fitting for a group of characters who are able to turn into animals) which used the <> without quotes to denote Though Speech from vocal dialog.   There was other "quotation subbing" used for aliens that used other forms of speech but Though Speak was the most consistent.

Comment: That was a perfect response this is really gonna help me out I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Well...

If your goal is to have your story accepted by a publisher as a no-name beginner author, or win first place in a contest, then this isn't the most promising strategy. Even if your story is actually good, it's going to have it harder to win the heart of an editor or judge. Unusual styles are especially popular with beginner writers, and these people have seen too many stories in an "edgy" or "experimental" style done for a self-serving sake, paired with overall inexperienced writing, so they tend to develop a sort of allergy to unusual forms.

But if you want to have fun with your writing and don't mind getting rejected or self-publishing online or creating something you end up discarding, then I say, go for whatever you feel like. I wouldn't worry it might ruin your sense of good writing, honestly I'd rather expect the opposite. By trying it out, and looking at the result, you're likely to get a firmer feeling for why some things tend to work better than others, or why some forms only work well in a limited type of context, or overdose the reader easily. It also gives you a ready array of options you can come back to and choose from when the time, topic, setting and so on is right for it. And a base for finding out the style you feel most at home with. All very positive things.

Writing in unusual styles as a beginner writer is a bit like wearing an extravagant hairstyle and experimenting with adventurous behaviour when you're young (and I don't mean just drinking but also outdoor sports or traveling or whatever). Most people don't stick with a lot of what they tried, but the experience is meaningful for their growing up.

Comment: Thanks that was just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The common advice for popular genre fiction that agents and experienced writers give is to follow the conventions of your genre as an unpublished aspiring writer. This pertains to all aspects of the work, such as length, tense, topics, viewpoints and so on, as well as style.

This advice does not hold true for literary fiction, though. There are segments of the market where innovation and experimentation are selling points.

Comment: I appreciate the input ill start with the basics before I go too wild